# How to empty the Active Block list in SelfControl?

Tags: productivity

I'd like to empty the **Active Block** list of hosts from this productivity software called SelfControl because some of these websites are duplicates. I've tried pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> key, right-clicking on the website entries, dragging them into the main window and then pressing the **Delete** button -- nothing works. Is there some work-around? Should I modify some configuration file? I downloaded the application as a `.deb` package from the official site.

[image: main window]
[image: block list]

Answer (score 3):

After much searching, here's how I solved the problem.

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/perl5/SelfControl/UI.pm
```

Place the cursor after

```
$list->set_data_array($self->{config}->{hosts});
$list->get_selection->set_mode('multiple');`
```

Add this code:

```
# we need the following line otherwise the list is too small
$list->set_size_request(350,500);

  my @columns = $list->get_columns;
  my $cnum = scalar(@columns);
  my $c;
  foreach $c (@columns) {
$c->set_resizable(TRUE);
  }

  my $rows = $self->{config}->{hosts};
  my $rnum = scalar(@$rows);

  if ($rnum > 10){ $rnum = 10; }
  if ($rnum < 2){ $rnum = 2; }

  $list->set_size_request (175 * $cnum, 28 * $rnum);
```

Save and close.

Try launching the app and see if it works.